# How to render conditionally in Angular?

Tags: angular

I just want to simply render the button conditionally rather than rendering `{{allcode}}` inside curly braces. I come from the react world, it's really feeling weird. How to achieve this?

Angular code - but it's still not working:

```
<td *ngFor="let column of requestColumns">
   {{ 
   row[column.value] === "Allow" ?
   <button>Allow</button> :
   row[column.value] === "Reject" ?            
   <button>Reject</button> :
   row[column.value]
   }}
</td> interpo
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to render what is in the `column.value` and have somewhat common logic:

```
<td *ngFor="let column of requestColumns">
 <button (click)="allowOrReject(column)">{{column.value}}</button>
</td>
```

If you have separate logic/methods for the buttons:

```
<td *ngFor="let column of requestColumns">
 <button *ngIf="column.value === 'Allow'" (click)="allow(column)">Allow</button>
 <button *ngIf="column.value === 'Reject'" (click)="reject(column)">Reject</button>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like below

```
<td *ngFor="let column of requestColumns">
   <button *ngIf="column.value === "Allow"">Allow</button> :
   <button *ngIf="column.value === "Reject""> Reject</button>
 </td>
```